# How use memcpy to initialize array in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, memcpy

I have simple struct:

```
typedef struct{
double par[4];
}struct_type;
```

I have also initialize function for it where one argument is a 4 elements array. How properly use **memcpy** to initalize array in struct? Something like this don't work for me:

```
 struct_type* init_fcn(double array[4]){

 struct _type* retVal;
 retVal->par=malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
 memcpy(retVal->par,&array);

return retVal;
}
```

I can init values one by one but i thnik memcpy will be better and faster. Do You have any ideas how to proper do it?

Comment: Oh I see, memcpy also requires the size of the array, which is the same as the size given to malloc

Comment: `sizeof(*double)` is nonsense and will result in a compiler error. This isn't a [mcve]

Comment: More like `memcpy(retVal->par, array, sizeof(double)*4)`. Also in malloc you use `sizeof(double)` (size of one element)

Comment: @StoryTeller It will not result in a compiler error, but in undefined behavior (or even well defined if doubles and pointers happen to have the same size)

Comment: Hi, yes use size of one element by multiply by 4 so for whole array.

Comment: @PaulStelian - Look closely at the bit I quoted. Where is the asterisk (`*`) located?

Comment: With the code you show, the variable `retVal` is a pointer, but *where does it point*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It point to malloc'ed memory. Then it is initialized.

Comment: @ArkadiuszKuleta Not in the code you ***show***. There `retVal` is uninitialized, so it will have an *indeterminate* value, and lead to *undefined behavior* when you dereference it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Must have been subsequently edited. It was `sizeof(double*)`

Comment: @PaulStelian - The edit history shows only the nonsense I quoted. But It was all edited away by now, so this discussion is moot.

Comment: @StoryTeller Guys, it was edited by me. Sorry for mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return a pointer to a new object of type `struct_type`, then you should create exactly such an object, i.e. use `malloc(sizeof(struct_type))` instead of allocating space for any members directly. So your code could look as follows:

```
struct_type* init_fcn(double array[4]){

    struct_type* retVal;
    retVal = malloc(sizeof(struct_type));
    if (retVal) {
        memcpy(retVal->par,array,sizeof(retVal->par));
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: @PSkocik: noticed right now and corrected it; thanks.

Comment: Thanks! It work for me. So is 'r->par' first value in par array and '&r-par' is adress of first element?

Comment: @ArkadiuszKuleta No. The first is the array, which in the context of a function call decays to the address of the first element, and the second is the address of the array, which is numerically the same. In this context, you can use r->par, &r->par, &r->par[0], and it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: @PSkocik: More accurately, `r->par` and `&r->par[0]` are the same type (`double *`) and value; `&r->par` is of type `double (*)[4]`, though its value as a `void *` is the same as `r->par` etc.